# proper function calling etiquette?

Tags: javascript

I may be wording this  title wrong but in javascript is it ok to call a nested function like so, if not why and what are some safer or more proper ways

```
function foo() {
return function poo() {
console.log("ew");
}
}

var fooPoo = foo()();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine, and fairly normal, if you want `poo` to have access to information that's private within `foo` and you don't want the calling code to have access to that information. Or even just if `foo` is what knows how to create the `poo` function, even if private information isn't needed.

It's *relatively* rare to do it all in one expression, because usually when you return a function from another function, you want to keep the function around:

```
var p = foo();
var fp1 = p();
var fp2 = p();
```

...but only *relatively* unusual, not unusual.

Here's an example of using the private information held by the context of the original call to the function (`allocator`, here, is like your `foo`):

```js
function allocator(seed) {
    return function() {
        return seed++;
    };
}

var a = allocator(1);
console.log(a()); // 1
console.log(a()); // 2
console.log(a()); // 3
```

Note that the code calling `a` can't manipulate `seed` directly. It can only call `a` and use the value it returns.

Comment: i see, most of it makes sense, but why is it that you would want to keep it around?

Comment: @NicholasRotondo: It completely depends on what the function is for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it as a functional technique referred to as `currying`. it allows you to set parameters for the function in different places in your code

```
function foo(param1) {
  return function poo(param2) {
    console.log(param1, param2);
  }
}

var fooPoo = foo('param1')('param2');
```

A common thing I do is use currying for passing in settings when running event listeners to allow greater reuse of functions

```
function setColor(color) {
  return function (e) {
    e.target.background = color
  }
}

someElement.addEventLister('click', setColor('red'))
```

Here you can pass in your configuration when declaring your event listener but it won't be called until later when the event is fired and due to the closure you will have access to the color variable within the event listener callback. But now that I know the technique I use it quite a bit